# "Skipped 75 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." running empty Compose app

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

i'm learning how to use **jetpack compose** in android project.
i just created new project and choose empty compose  activity template,
after build finished i run application on Android Emulator.
it successfully run but in **Run** logs it keep showing info log as

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 75 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

i'm worried about this issue.
can anyone please help me for this issue i will be very thankful.

[log error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXnR7.png)

Comment: That's nothing to worry about, you can just ignore it.

Answer (score 4):

That's nothing to worry about.  Emulator performance isn't necessarily representative of real device performance and is often slower due to the overhead of running a second operating system (Android) within your operating system.  This is especially true if you don't have the emulator's various hardware acceleration options enabled.

Also, apps run from Studio are debuggable, which disables a number of the optimizations that ART (the Android runtime) would be able to perform on a release app.  Plus it needs a bit to load the code into memory and perform just-in-time compilation of the Compose framework.

Bottom line: Don't worry about performance unless you see issues in release mode on a real device.